# Creating Video Watch Time Retention Plot using Plotly and Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, data-analysis

I have a table like this:

```
videoId  userId  viewedMintues  totalMinutes    
1007975  275308   10               26       
1009304  304392    6                6       
1009343  463588    3               23       
100941   462406    1               26       
100941   463199   12               26
100941   453169   23               26
```

And so on. So I want to create a cohort retention graph using `plotly` in `python`. But first of all I want to make a table something like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
            | viewedMintues | no_of_users | totalMinutes 
    videoId |  1            |  20         |   26
    100941  |  2            |  19         |   26
            |  3            |  19         |   26
            |  4            |  15         |   26
               ...             ...            ...
            |  19           |  5          |   26
            |  20           |  4          |   26 
------------------------------------------------------------
```

And so on. After the above table is made, I want to create a wave-like graph for each `videoId` using `for loop subplot`, with plot title as `videoId`, `viewedMintues` in X-axis and `no_of_users` or `% of users` in the Y-axis of the graph, so that I can understand which is the point of time (the minute) when max. users are dropping out.How do I do it?

Also there's another issue like:

```
videoId  userId  viewedMinutes  totalMinutes
100941   24467    13             26
100941   24467    19             26
```

In the above case I want to drop duplicates, keeping the `max` minutes watched by an user and filter out the minimum values.

P.S. `no_of_users` in the second table corresponds to unique no. of users watching the video at that minute, which we can get from something like `pd.Series.userId.nunique()`.

Update:

I've been able to make a dataframe like this:

```
                                                 TotalUsers
videoId CohortGroup viewedMinutes   totalMinutes    
1017479       0             0         5               8
                            1         5               3
                            2         5               2
                            4         5               3
                            5         5               19
```

But here it is like no. of users who viewed till that minute. So in this case total no. of viewers are 35 for this particular `videoId`. So in `TotalUsers` I want it like this:

```
                                                   TotalUsers
videoId CohortGroup viewedMinutes   totalMinutes    
1017479       0             0         5               35
                            1         5               27 (35-8)
                            2         5               24 (27-3)
                            4         5               22 (24-2)
                            5         5               19 (22-3)
```

P.P.S. I want to create more of a video watching retention cohort, something like this ([Retentionchart.jpg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18P4T6cevBfBy87IE8XQT_6Mx3Kj2uOR4)).

Comment: Can you provide some input and desired output data that directly correspond to eachother? It's a little difficult to understand what's going on at the moment.

Comment: Yes I understand that - but at the moment it is not clear how the values in your second table relate to the values in your first table. For example, the `totalMinutes` for `videoId` 100941 are 12 in the first table but 26 in the second. Take a look at how to create a [mcve].

Comment: sorry for the mistake. Updated, please check

Comment: What happens if a user watches a video more than once? Do you just want to take their maximum watching length, or do you want them to be counted twice in the second table?

Comment: I have added an updated dataframe that I have been able to form, any further help from this point?